# Group Project Theater seating switch statement

Tags: c++

Trying to keep the main as simple as possible, but couldn't get it to work. IN the code there is a switch statement in the main, but I need each case in the switch statement to be put into seperate functions. Please help!

choice = menu();

```
    switch(choice)

    {

    case 1:

        cout <<"Seating Prices\n\n";

        for(int count=0;count<ROWS; count++)

        {

            cout <<"The price for row " << (count+1) <<": $";

            cout <<price[count] <<endl;

            getch();

        }

        break;

    case 2:

        cout <<"Purchase Tickets\n\n";

        do

        {

            cout <<"Please enter the row: ";

            cin >>rowChoice;

            cout <<"Please enter the seat: ";

            cin >>seatChoice;

            if(seating[rowChoice][seatChoice] == '*')

            {

                cout <<"That seat is unavailable please make another selection.\n";

            }

            else

            {

                cost = price[rowChoice] + 0;

                total += cost;

                cout <<"Ticket price: " <<cost <<endl;

                cout <<"Please confirm your purchase.  Enter 1 for yes, 2 for no.";

                cin >>confirm;

                if(confirm==1)

                {

                    cout <<"Your ticket purchase has been confirmed.\n";

                        seating[rowChoice][seatChoice] = TAKEN;

                        ticketSales++;

                }

                else if (confirm==2)

                {

                    cout <<"Would you like to purchase another ticket?  Enter 1 for yes, 2 for no." <<endl;

                    cin >>quit;

                }

                cout <<"Would you like to purchase another ticket?  Enter 1 for yes, 2 for no.";

                cin >>quit;

            }

        }

        while (quit==1);

        break;



    case 3:

        int viewRow;

        cout <<"View Seats by Row\n\n";

        cout <<"Enter the row you would like to view";

        cin >>viewRow;

        seatingChartRow(viewRow);

        cout <<"Press 1 to return to the main menu.";

        cin >>quit;

        break;


    case 4:

        cout <<"Sales Statistics\n\n";
        saleStats ();

            break;

    case 5:

        cout <<"Quit\n";

        break;

    default: cout <<"Error Input\n";

    }

}
```

Comment: "_Couldn't get it to work_" is not really an adequate problem report. What were you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: When I had the switch statement in the main it worked fine. However when I put it in separate functions if failed to work. I don't know if I'm calling the functions wrong, messing up the function definition of something else.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
choice = menu();
switch(choice)
{
case 1:
    seating();
    break;
case 2:
    buy_tickets();
    break;
case 3:
    view_seats();
    break;
case 4:
    saleStats ();
    break;
case 5:
    cout <<"Quit\n";
    break;
default: cout <<"Error Input\n";
}
```

And do your cin/cout stuff in the requisite function.

You even did this yourself for saleStats, so not sure what the confusion is?